# tortoisehg workbench on windows 10 not opening

Tags: mercurial, windows-10, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I downloaded the tortoisehg app from the official site [here](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) and that is 4.6.1 and when I click on the tortoishg workbench and it's not opening and no error shown, and when I even try to clone with command line I get this error

```
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.4.1)
** Extensions loaded:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 61, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 85, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 173, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 313, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 321, in _callcatch
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 154, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 303, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 940, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 701, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 948, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 937, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1183, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1425, in clone
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 670, in clone
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 1294, in pull
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 1936, in _maybeapplyclonebundle
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 2119, in trypullbundlefromurl
  File "mercurial\bundle2.pyo", line 342, in applybundle
  File "mercurial\bundle2.pyo", line 449, in processbundle
  File "mercurial\bundle2.pyo", line 456, in processparts
  File "mercurial\bundle2.pyo", line 523, in _processpart
  File "mercurial\bundle2.pyo", line 1620, in handlechangegroup
  File "mercurial\bundle2.pyo", line 459, in _processchangegroup
  File "mercurial\changegroup.pyo", line 341, in apply
  File "mercurial\changegroup.pyo", line 972, in _addchangegroupfiles
  File "mercurial\ui.pyo", line 1552, in progress
  File "mercurial\progress.pyo", line 301, in progress
  File "mercurial\progress.pyo", line 156, in show
    File "mercurial\encoding.pyo", line 227, in colwidth
   LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001
```

I don't know what it the problem I always setup the app and everything goes smooth, please advice if anything I must install first or check to everything work fine

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You  may need to file an issue at https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/

Comment: ok @DaveInCaz , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asked [here](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/) in the official issue list (Thanks to @DaveInCaz), I get the solution

"
cp65001 (a Windows variant of UTF-8) appears not supported on Python 2.x.

Workaround: set HGENCODING=utf8 environment variable.
"

and here is the [link](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5127/tortoisehg-workbench-on-windows-10-not).